# (Php)Retrieve primary key of previous table and insert into current table

Tags: php

Im new to php scripting.. I want to know if there is any mistake in my php script that i want to fetch income_id (primary key in income table) from income table and insert it into expenses table(as foreign key)...I able to add all data into expenses table except the income_id..

```js
<?php 

 //Importing our db connection script
 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 
 //Getting values
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $income_id = $_POST['income_id'];
 $category = $_POST['category'];
 $amount = $_POST['amount'];
 $date = date('Y-m-d');

 $sql = "SELECT income_id from `income` where id='".$id."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 //Creating an sql query
 $sql = "INSERT INTO expenses (income_id,category,amount,date) VALUES ('$rows[income_id]','$category','$amount','$date')";
 
 //Executing query to database
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 echo 'Added Successfully';
 }else{
 echo 'Could Not Add';
 }
 
 //Closing the database 
 mysqli_close($con);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest joining both queries:

```sql
INSERT INTO expenses (income_id, category, amount, date)
VALUES ((SELECT income_id FROM `income` WHERE id='$id'), '$category', '$amount', '$date')
```

Comment: Sorry..even I joining both queries also not working..the data could not add into the database...i don't know whats the problem though...